# Document Analysis Client error: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, azure

I've been struggling with a weird error when trying to use the Form Recognizer API. I have tried the exact same code in two different Windows environments with Python 3.11 (just instantiating a DocumentAnalysisClient and performing OCR on some documents), and while one works perfectly, the other returns raises the following:

```
ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C40253F590>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

The full code is:

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint = ENDPOINT, 
                                                  credential = AzureKeyCredential(KEY_CREDENTIAL))
poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(
    model_id="prebuilt-read", 
 document_url=my_document_url)
```

From what I've gathered it may be related to Windows' environment variables or some proxy-related stuff, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. Does anybody know what the fix might be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023F77748F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The error occurs due to the client is not able to establish a connection with the server make sure your internet connectivity is and check if you have set the correct endpoint and key credentials for the DocumentAnalysisClient **`ENDPOINT,`** **`KEY_CREDENTIAL`** and check any firewall rules that are blocking the connection.

After checking all in my environment I used the below code to use the Form Recognizer API to analyze a document from a URL using the `DocumentAnalysisClient`.

**Code:**

```
import os
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient

ENDPOINT = "xxx"
KEY_CREDENTIAL = "xxxx"

my_document_url ="xxxx"
document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint=ENDPOINT, credential=AzureKeyCredential(KEY_CREDENTIAL))
poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(model_id="prebuilt-read", document_url=my_document_url)
result = poller.result()
print(result.content)
```

**Output:**

```
The Guide for Writing Word Documents in Microsoft Word for EasyChair Publications
Andrei Voronkov1,2 and Kryštof Hoder1
Masterminded EasyChair and created the first stable version of this document
Created the first draft of this document
1 EasyChair
2 University of Manchester, Manchester, U.K.
andrei@voronkov.com, hoderk@cs.man.ac.uk
Abstract
In order to ease the lives of authors, editors, and trees, we present a manual and an example of the use of Microsoft Word and similar tools for creating documents for EasyChair-based electronic and on-paper publishing in the EPiC Series and Kalpa Publications series.
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure AI Document Intelligence client library for Python | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ai-documentintelligence-readme?view=azure-python-preview#using-prebuilt-models)